# How to Convert row to columns on mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

This is my query :

```sql
SELECT tarih, band_no, opr_liste_no, operasyon_adi, saat, SUM(uretim)
  FROM operasyonlar10dk
 WHERE tarih = '2021-03-23'
   AND band_no = '1'
   AND SUBSTRING(saat, 4, 2) = '00'
 GROUP BY saat, operasyon_adi, opr_liste_no
 ORDER BY saat, opr_liste_no, operasyon_adi
```

This query output picture 1:

[image]

Picture 2 :

[image]

it goes on like this to hour 23:00:00

I need this like table =>

[image]

How can I create a mysql query of such a table.I will be glad if you can help me guys.I uploaded the csv file if anyone wants to review it.To view the data properly, open it in utf-8 format.

Csv File Link: https://easyupload.io/4as2ph

Fixed like this

```
        SELECT tarih, band_no, opr_liste_no, operasyon_adi, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN saat= '08:00:00' THEN uretim ELSE NULL END) AS '08:00:00', 
        SUM(CASE WHEN saat= '09:00:00' THEN uretim ELSE NULL END) AS '09:00:00', 
        SUM(CASE WHEN saat= '10:00:00' THEN uretim ELSE NULL END) AS '10:00:00',
        SUM(CASE WHEN saat= '11:00:00' THEN uretim ELSE NULL END) AS '11:00:00',
        SUM(CASE WHEN saat= '12:00:00' THEN uretim ELSE NULL END) AS '12:00:00',
        SUM(CASE WHEN saat= '13:00:00' THEN uretim ELSE NULL END) AS '13:00:00', 
        SUM(CASE WHEN saat= '14:00:00' THEN uretim ELSE NULL END) AS '14:00:00', 
        SUM(CASE WHEN saat= '15:00:00' THEN uretim ELSE NULL END) AS '15:00:00', 
        SUM(CASE WHEN saat= '16:00:00' THEN uretim ELSE NULL END) AS '16:00:00', 
        SUM(CASE WHEN saat= '17:00:00' THEN uretim ELSE NULL END) AS '17:00:00', 
        SUM(CASE WHEN saat= '18:00:00' THEN uretim ELSE NULL END) AS '18:00:00', 
        SUM(CASE WHEN saat= '19:00:00' THEN uretim ELSE NULL END) AS '19:00:00', 
        SUM(CASE WHEN saat= '20:00:00' THEN uretim ELSE NULL END) AS '20:00:00', 
        SUM(CASE WHEN saat= '21:00:00' THEN uretim ELSE NULL END) AS '21:00:00', 
        SUM(CASE WHEN saat= '22:00:00' THEN uretim ELSE NULL END) AS '22:00:00', 
        SUM(CASE WHEN saat= '23:00:00' THEN uretim ELSE NULL END) AS '23:00:00'
        FROM operasyonlar10dk WHERE tarih = '2021-03-23' 
    AND band_no = '1' AND SUBSTRING(saat, 4, 2) = '00'
 GROUP BY operasyon_adi, opr_liste_no ORDER BY saat, opr_liste_no, operasyon_adi
```

Link of helpful video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1HDzBrfa4fU

Comment: As you should know, there's much easier to help you when you post text data, instead of pictures.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I return pivot table output in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/how-can-i-return-pivot-table-output-in-mysql)

Comment: I checked but it doesn't help